# Writing test cases for Retrofit

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit, dagger-2

I have a class `DeparturePresenter` I want to write a simple test case with `Mockito` for it. The`DeparturePresenter` is a simple Interface that `Retrofit` invokes to create the appropriated API calling. The problem is I don't know how to call the method which returns an `Observable` object in `Mockito`.

```
public class MainServiceDaggerTest {

@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
@Mock
DeparturePresenter departurePresenter;

@Mock
private FlixService mApiService;

@Test
public void testService(){
    when( mApiService.getDepartures()).thenReturn(/*What should be here?*/)
}
```

My `Interface` is this.

```
@Singleton
public interface FlixService {
@GET("/mobile/v1/network/station/10/timetable")
   public Observable<Response> getDepartures();
}
```

Comment: What method are you trying to test? Are you testing getDepartures or mocking it? You can't do both

Comment: @MichaelDodd It's not a duplicated question

Comment: @JacobSTL I want to test getDepartures

Comment: @matio Both questions deal with the mocking of a response from a retrofit call, particularly one that returns `Observable<Response>`. The solution would be to return a mock `Response` wrapped in `Observable.just()` in an identical manner to the other question, therefore I believe it to be a duplicate.